# How to let chartist legend redraw once chartist data series changed

Tags: reactjs, legend, chartist.js

I am creating a dashboard which contains a stacked bar chart. I use the react chartis.js with the chartist-plugin-legend.

The thing I found is, if I init the chart with all data defined already, just as it's example, then the legend can shows up.

However, in my case, the chart's data is binding with a state, and the data series changed in componentDidMount(), where I fetch all the data and set the state with updated value.The legend will not displayed in this case.

I noticed the chartist-plugin-legend plugin only append the legend element in chart's 'created' event. So that's may be the reason I cannot see the legend once data got updated later.

So is there any way to force let legend redraw?

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchMetricsData(xxxxx)
}
```

Within fetchMetricsData:

```
fetch('xxxxxxxx', {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "xxxx",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(json => {
              this.setState({data:json.data})
        });
```

For render part:

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const that = this;
    return (
        <GridContainer>
            <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                <Card>
                    <CardHeader color="info" icon>
                        <h4 className={classes.cardIconTitle}></h4>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>

                        <ChartistGraph
                            data={this.state.data}
                            type="Bar"
                            options={stackMetricsChart.options}
                            listener={{draw: that.onMetricDataDraw}}
                        />
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>
    );
}
```

For chartist option:

```
require('chartist-plugin-legend')
const stackMetricsChart = {
options: {
    axisX: {
        showGrid: false
    },
    low: 0,
    chartPadding: {
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0
    },
    seriesBarDistance: 22,
    stackBars: true,
    plugins: [
        Chartist.plugins.tooltip(),
        Chartist.plugins.legend({
            position: 'bottom'
           }
        )
    ]
}};
```

Comment: How about sharing your code with us?

Comment: @PowerStat, I updated some code in the question